# How to put footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, footer

I tried to put footer to the bottom, but get something weird
I use mui

Just created empty example page to show footer place
[image]

code in app.js

```
<>
<Header />
      <Divider />
      <Container>
        <Routes>
 <Route path='/main' element={<IndexMain />} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
      <Footer />
<>
```

Footer code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-field-6g4isg?file=/src/Footer.js)

example page code from pic

```
import React from 'react'

function IndexMain() {
  return (
    <div>Index</div>
  )
}

export default IndexMain
```

what I do wrong?

Comment: If the page doesn't have content with defined height, your footer could in fact be at the bottom of your currently created page. If you want it fixed at the bottom you can use position: fixed; bottom: 0 in CSS, or other options like position: absolute - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp. If you just want to check whether the footer is in fact the bottom of your content, you can use height: 100vh for your root component on the page.

Comment: @Ross so now it fixed at the bottom of the page, but it on other elements and if I scroll - it is fixed

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 easy ways to adjust the footer at the bottom.

Option 1: Using margin-top auto

```css
    .content{
      min-height: calc(100vh - 100px) /* you have to minus header and footer width 
      together*/
    }
    .footer {
      margin-top: 0; /* take available whitespace */
      margin-bottom: -10px;      /* remove bottom whitespace */
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      height: 100px;            /* calc height when limited content */
      }
```

Option 2: Using position absolute

```css
    .page-container {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .content-wrap {
      padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
    }
    
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
    }
```